# Using React to create table from data

Tags: reactjs, html-table

as the question suggests I am brand new to react and am trying to create a table to display some data.

Here's what I have so far

```
const { Component } = React;
const { render } = ReactDOM;

class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            cars: [
                {
                    "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                    "model": "Rav4",
                    "year": 2008,
                    "stock": 3,
                    "price": 8500
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                    "model": "Camry",
                    "year": 2009,
                    "stock": 2,
                    "price": 6500
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Toyota",
                    "model": "Tacoma",
                    "year": 2016,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "price": 22000
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "BMW",
                    "model": "i3",
                    "year": 2012,
                    "stock": 5,
                    "price": 12000
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Chevy",
                    "model": "Malibu",
                    "year": 2015,
                    "stock": 2,
                    "price": 10000
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Honda",
                    "model": "Accord",
                    "year": 2013,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "price": 9000
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Hyundai",
                    "model": "Elantra",
                    "year": 2013,
                    "stock": 2,
                    "price": 7000
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Chevy",
                    "model": "Cruze",
                    "year": 2012,
                    "stock": 2,
                    "price": 5500
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Dodge",
                    "model": "Charger",
                    "year": 2013,
                    "stock": 2,
                    "price": 16000
                },

                {
                    "manufacturer": "Ford",
                    "model": "Mustang",
                    "year": 2009,
                    "stock": 1,
                    "price": 8000
                },]
        };
    }

    render() {
      const columns = [{
        Header: 'Manufacturer',
        accessor: 'manufacturer'
      },{
        Header: 'Model',
        accessor: 'model'
      },{
        Header: 'Year',
        accessor: 'year'
      },{
        Header: 'Stock',
        accessor: 'stock'
      },{
        Header: 'Price',
        accessor: 'price'
      },{
        Header: 'Option',
        accessor: 'option'
      }]
        return (
            <div>
            <Table
              data = {this.state.cars}
              colums = {columns}
              />
            </div>
        );
    };
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

Im getting errors that the table is not defined but when I try to define it, that throws me errors as well. The table doesn't need to be fancy, the simpler the better in fact.

I was thinking of doing something like what was done in this post: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/212250/generating-a-table-based-on-an-array-of-objects.

Any suggestions?

UPDATE

After the very helpful comment from Crispen Gari, I made some tweaks and came up with this

```
class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     cars: [
       {
          manufacturer: "Toyota",
          model: "Rav4",
          year: 2008,
          stock: 3,
          price: 8500,
        },

       {
         manufacturer: "Toyota",
         model: "Camry",
         year: 2009,
         stock: 2,
         price: 6500,
      },
      {
         manufacturer: "Toyota",
         model: "Tacoma",
      year: 2016,
      stock: 1,
      price: 22000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "BMW",
      model: "i3",
      year: 2012,
      stock: 5,
      price: 12000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Chevy",
      model: "Malibu",
      year: 2015,
      stock: 2,
      price: 10000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Honda",
      model: "Accord",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 1,
      price: 9000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Hyundai",
      model: "Elantra",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 2,
      price: 7000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Chevy",
      model: "Cruze",
      year: 2012,
      stock: 2,
      price: 5500,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Dodge",
      model: "Charger",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 2,
      price: 16000,
    },

    {
         manufacturer: "Ford",
         model: "Mustang",
         year: 2009,
         stock: 1,
          price: 8000,
        },
      ],
    };
 }
render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <Table data={this.state.cars} />
   </div>
 );
}
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const tableHeads = Object.keys(this.props.data[0]);
    return (
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
         {tableHeads.map((tableHead, i) => (
           <th key={i}>{tableHead}</th>
         ))}
        </thead>
       <tbody>
         {this.props.data.map((value, key) => (
           <tr key={key}>
              <td>{value.manufacturer}</td>
              <td>{value.model}</td>
              <td>{value.year}</td>
              <td>{value.stock}</td>
              <td>{value.price}</td>
          </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
     </table>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"))
```

This post can be considered closed

Comment: I would suggest you start by trying by yourself or looking in some tutorials and replicate it. It would be more suitable to open the question with some implementation where you can have proper feedback on refining your code, and fixing your errors.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but I have been trying using various guides, stack posts, and tutorials,etc. I typically post on here as a last resort to help me get the ball rolling. You could try suggesting something more helpful, like a guide you recommend, or a direction to start in. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hey*, Try this code if you face any problems of understanding, let me know. **I recommend you to copy and paste this code if it works go through it and try to understand. The most important thing is to understand JavaScript higher order function `map`**

```
 import React from "react";

class App extends React.Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);

   this.state = {
     cars: [
       {
          manufacturer: "Toyota",
          model: "Rav4",
          year: 2008,
          stock: 3,
          price: 8500,
        },

       {
         manufacturer: "Toyota",
         model: "Camry",
         year: 2009,
         stock: 2,
         price: 6500,
      },
      {
         manufacturer: "Toyota",
         model: "Tacoma",
      year: 2016,
      stock: 1,
      price: 22000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "BMW",
      model: "i3",
      year: 2012,
      stock: 5,
      price: 12000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Chevy",
      model: "Malibu",
      year: 2015,
      stock: 2,
      price: 10000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Honda",
      model: "Accord",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 1,
      price: 9000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Hyundai",
      model: "Elantra",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 2,
      price: 7000,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Chevy",
      model: "Cruze",
      year: 2012,
      stock: 2,
      price: 5500,
    },

    {
      manufacturer: "Dodge",
      model: "Charger",
      year: 2013,
      stock: 2,
      price: 16000,
    },

    {
         manufacturer: "Ford",
         model: "Mustang",
         year: 2009,
         stock: 1,
          price: 8000,
        },
      ],
    };
 }

render() {
 return (
   <div>
     <Table data={this.state.cars} />
   </div>
 );
}
}

class Table extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props);
  }

  render() {
    const tableHeads = Object.keys(this.props?.data[0]);
    return (
      <table border="1">
        <thead>
         {tableHeads.map((tableHead, i) => (
           <th key={i}>{tableHead}</th>
         ))}
        </thead>
       <tbody>
         {this.props?.data?.map((value, key) => (
           <tr key={key}>
              <td>{value?.manufacturer}</td>
              <td>{value?.model}</td>
              <td>{value?.year}</td>
              <td>{value?.stock}</td>
              <td>{value?.price}</td>
          </tr>
         ))}
       </tbody>
     </table>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

**I Hope this will help you, Good Luck**

Comment: First, thanks for your comment! It does help a bit to have some idea of how someone else might handle this situation. My compiler is very picky and currently I'm trying to rewrite your ternary(?) operators. Can you tell me what the intention was with these? 
Here's an example of how I'm trying to rewrite these

Comment: `const tableHeads = Object.keys ? (this.props.data[0]) : null;`

Comment: I made some tweaks to the changes you made and was able to do what I needed to do. Thanks again for your comment!

Comment: `?` operator protects some runtime errors just in case an object is null we don't want to read the property if the object is null. In React if for example you want to read `this.props.data[0]` and `this.props` is a null object it will throw an error saying `can not read the property data of undefined` so to avoid such error we use `this.props?.data[0]`